# Individual buttons in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, imagebutton

Most talk about buttons for cocos2d seems to be directed to CCMenu, where CCMenu AFAIK is meant for having a row or column in center of screen.
I need to place buttons randomly on screen and have yet to find a simple out of the box solution for this. I did try CCControlButton but didn't get it to work (CCScale9Sprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName loads incorrectly from sprite atlas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better way which I changed to.

Put this in like init:

```
        CCMenuItem* menuitemRetry = [[self class] buttonWithSpriteframenameOff:@"retry_off.png" on:@"retry_on.png" at:ccp(198, 184) block:^(id sender) {
            // Do something
        }];
        CCMenuItem* menuitemMenu = [[self class] buttonWithSpriteframenameOff:@"menu_off.png" on:@"menu_on.png" at:ccp(362, 184) block:^(id sender) {
            // Do something else
        }];
        CCMenu* menuLow = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuitemMenu, menuitemRetry, nil];
        menuLow.position = CGPointZero;
        [self addChild:menuLow];
```

This also needed

```
+(CCMenuItem*)buttonWithSpriteframenameOff:(NSString*)spriteframenameOff on:(NSString*)spriteframeOn at:(const CGPoint)POINT block:(void(^)(id sender))block {
    CCMenuItem* menuitem = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteframenameOff] selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteframeOn] block:block];
    menuitem.position = POINT;
    return menuitem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For now I try to use this. It uses only one button in each CCMenu. So my screen will have lots of CCMenu instances, one for each button.

```
+(CCMenu*)button:(NSString*)spriteframename at:(const CGPoint)POINT block:(void(^)(id sender))block {
    CCSprite* sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteframename];
    CCSprite* sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteframename];
    CCMenuItem* menuitem = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalSprite:sprite1 selectedSprite:sprite2 block:block];
    CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuitem, nil];
    menu.contentSize = sprite1.contentSize;
    menu.position = POINT;
    return menu;
}
```

Comment: CCMenu is the container for menu items (you can mix different kinds of menu items in a single menu), and provides the underlying menu items with the requisite touch processing.  One menu item per menu is just fine ...